# Linking wxWidgets with cMake libwx files not found

Tags: cmake, linker, mingw, wxwidgets, msys

I build wxWidgets-3.1.0 with MSYS with the following commands: ../configure --prefix=/mingw --enable-shared and make && make install. I can run samples such as minimal.cpp without problems. When trying to link wxWidgets in my cmake I get the following errors:

g++.exe: error: /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_mswu_core-3.1.a: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a: No such file or directory

I checked the lib folder, and these files do exist as you can see:
[lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pCmT.png)

When running wx-config --libs I get the following output:

-L/C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib   -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_mswu_xrc-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_mswu_qa-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_mswu_html-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_mswu_adv-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_mswu_core-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a /C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a -lwxregexu-3.1 -lwxexpat-3.1 -lwxtiff-3.1 -lwxjpeg-3.1 -lwxpng-3.1 -lz -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lgdi32

The cmake should be fine and the wxWidgets package is found. Below the linking of the wxWidgets library. The second line gives the errors.

```
add_executable(GUI ${GUI_BUILD_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(GUI ${LIBS} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: which command is generated for linking?

Comment: Well the line in the cmake "target_link_libraries(GUI ${LIBS} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})" links the wxWidgets libraries to the GUI executable. I use "$ cmake ../ -G "MSYS Makefiles"" to run the cmake from the MSYS terminal. The cmake file looks as the example below on this -> [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindwxWidgets.html) page.

Comment: you probably misunderstood - I asked you what command is executed when you issue `make`. You probably should run make with the verbose output to see it.

Comment: Im sorry It is the following:  /C/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe  -I/C/wxWidgets-3.1.0/include   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/GUI.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o GUI.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libGUI.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/GUI.dir/linklibs.rsp

Comment: I don't see a `find_package()` statement. Did you place it somewhere?